# Summing the variables with same column name in R

Tags: r, bind, gsub

I have a dataframe with column names;

```
[1] "sample_id"                                           "seq91 Acinetobacter;junii"                          
[3] "seq157 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"                        "seq139 Acinetobacter;johnsonii-lwoffii"             
[5] "seq225 Acinetobacter;johnsonii"                      "seq224 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"                       
[7] "seq278 Acinetobacter;calcoaceticus"                  "seq327 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"                       
[9] "seq309 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"                        "seq508 Acinetobacter;ursingii"                      
[11] "seq394 Acinetobacter;haemolyticus"                   "seq540 Acinetobacter;bouvetii"                      
[13] "seq558 Acinetobacter;bouvetii"                       "seq541 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"                       
[15] "seq575 Acinetobacter;haemolyticus-johnsonii-lwoffii" "seq665 Acinetobacter;junii"                         
[17] "seq707 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"                        "seq755 Acinetobacter;haemolyticus-johnsonii-lwoffii"
[19] "seq677 Acinetobacter;marinus"                        "seq758 Acinetobacter;johnsonii"                     
[21] "seq836 Acinetobacter;junii"                          "seq768 Acinetobacter;septicus-ursingii"             
[23] "seq770 Acinetobacter;bouvetii-johnsonii"             "seq928 Acinetobacter;tjernbergiae"                  
[25] "seq864 Acinetobacter;harbinensis"                    "seq902 Acinetobacter;parvus"
```

After removing seqxxx numbers, I want to  sum up the values of columns with same name. As the column names must be unique, how can I perform summation after getting rid of the seq and numbers? Thank you

Note: Previous version of my question was including removing seqxxx numbers and kind of violating the rule of this website by asking more than one questions in one post. Excuse me for such unwitting posting.

Comment: add `dput` of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing on the following pattern:

```
^.*?(?=\bAcinetobacter\b)
```

Then, just replace whatever the above captures with empty string.  Here is a sample:

```
x <- "seq157 Acinetobacter;lwoffii"
output <- sub("^.*?(?=\\bAcinetobacter\\b)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "Acinetobacter;lwoffii"
```